# UIView not accepting UIViewControllers data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a GameOver UIView that I call from inside my main UIViewController. It is just a 'popover' window that has the text game over, the score, and some blur effects to blur the main UIViewcontroller.

I try to pass an int to the UIView, but it doesn't accept it unless it is in the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`  method.

If I move the score label to drawRect method, the label is updated. But the blur effects go away.

*What am I doing wrong?*

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "GameOverView.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    GameOverView    * gov;
}

- (void) showGameOver {
    gov = [[GameOverView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    NSLog(@"Passing score of: %i", self.score);
    gov.finalScore = self.score;
    [self.view addSubview:gov];
}
```

**GameOverView.h**

```
@interface GameOverView : UIView {}
@property (nonatomic) int finalScore;
@end
```

**GameOverView.M**

```
@implementation GameOverView
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        //self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        NSLog(@"Score:%i", self.finalScore  );

        UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
        blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

        UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
        visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        visualEffectView.frame = super.bounds;
        [super addSubview:visualEffectView];

        UILabel * lblGameOver  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, frame.size.width, 200)];
        lblGameOver.center = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, 100);
        lblGameOver.text =   [NSString stringWithFormat: @"GAME OVER %i", self.finalScore];
        [self addSubview:lblGameOver];

        UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, 200)];
        button.center = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, 200);
        [button setTitle:@"Start New Game" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(removeSelfFromSuperview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:button];

    }
    return self;
}
- (void) removeSelfFromSuperview{
     [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: do u have any problem with the view background colour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *finalScore* property in the init method of the *GameOverView* class, but you are only setting its value after initializing it.

Change your initialization method to

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame finalScore:(int)fs{
        // use 'fs' instead of 'self.finalScore'
    }
```

It should work.

Comment: I ended up doing this. Overriding the initWithFrame.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how there isn't any problem with the view background color. You are initializing the view and adding it as subview like this:

```
 gov = [[GameOverView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
gov.finalScore = self.score;
[self.view addSubview:gov];
```

This will give the view background color as black which is default color. So you don't find much difference if you use blur effect.

you need to give the color for the view during the initialization :

```
     gov = [[GameOverView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[gov setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
[self.view addSubview:gov];
```

If you are planning to keep the code in initWithFrame, you don't need to worry about setting the background color. If you keep the code in drawRect, then you must set the background color,else it will be black color.

When coming to setting the score label, it doesn't matter whether you put it in drawRect or initWithFrame method. Make sure you use `drawRect` method only if you really have to draw on the view,so that you can call it later by using `setNeedsDisplay`